# UIScrollView paging enabled with content inset is working strange

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I created the UIScrollView with content insets.

```
scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(-80, 180, 480, 190)
self.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 160, 0, 160);
self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
[self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(480, 190)];

// Add three Views
[self.scrollView addSubview:view1];
[self.scrollView addSubview:view2];
[self.scrollView addSubview:view3];

[view1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 160, 190)];
[view2 setFrame:CGRectMake(160, 0, 160, 190)];
[view3 setFrame:CGRectMake(320, 0, 160, 190)];
```

[image: d]

At first time, `scrollView.contentOffset.x` was -160.0

But the weird problem is when I tap on scrollView(Yellow Area), content offset x value is resetting to 0 and shown like this.

[image]

I tried several times, but tapping on Scroll View resets the content offset to 0.

How can I prevent this?

Comment: what's the frame of `scrollView`?

Comment: scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(-80, 180, 480, 190). I'm going to make like gallery.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`UIScrollView` paging works by scrolling pages with the same width of the scrollView (in your case pages of 480 width). This means that you have 1 single page (you'd still be able to scroll left and right due to the 160 content inset).

One way to make this work would be:

```
self.scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(80, 180, 160, 190);
self.scrollView.clipsToBounds = NO;
self.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
[self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(480, 190)];
```

This will draw and scroll correctly, however, the sides of the screen will not be interactive (80 pixels on each side, since the control starts at frame.origin.x=80 and ends at 80+160=240).

Second option would be to handle paging yourself, by using methods provided by `UIScrollViewDelegate`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // pageIndex must be declared as a class member - this is used to prevent skipping pages during scroll
    pageIndex = 0;
    self.scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 180, 320, 190);
    self.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 80, 0, 80);
    self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = NO;
    self.scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(480, 190)];
    self.scrollView.delegate = self;
}

- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset{
    int pageWidth = 160;
    int pageX = pageIndex*pageWidth-scrollView.contentInset.left;
    if (targetContentOffset->x<pageX) {
        if (pageIndex>0) {
            pageIndex--;
        }
    }
    else if(targetContentOffset->x>pageX){
        if (pageIndex<3) {
            pageIndex++;
        }
    }
    targetContentOffset->x = pageIndex*pageWidth-scrollView.contentInset.left;
    NSLog(@"%d %d", pageIndex, (int)targetContentOffset->x);
}
```

Comment: I need paging and contentinset, because I want to see out of content view.

Comment: The scrollview don't have single page, because it has contentInset, it has 3 pages

Comment: page width is `480` (since that's the width of your `scrollview)`; `insets` are together `320`, which is less than 1 page. In any case, using `contentInset` is not the way to go since it doesn't go very well with paging, and the pages wouldn't contain the views that you expect, unless you center each view inside its 480 wide page.

Comment: You can look at the code, one page width = scrollview width(480) - insets(320) = 160, and content width = 480, so page = 3

Comment: it doesn't work like that. In the documentation for `pagingEnabled` it says: `If the value of this property is YES, the scroll view stops on multiples of the scroll view’s bounds when the user scrolls`. The bounds are not affected by `contentInset`.

Comment: `...however, the sides of the screen will not be interactive.` An easy way to get around this is to add the scroll view's pan gesture recognizer to the parent view. It will allow it to receive touches anywhere and still scroll the scroll view as normal: `parentView.addGestureRecognizer(scrollView.panGestureRecognizer)`. This is a technique Apple itself recommended in one of the WWDC scroll view sessions.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to alex's first approach with setting clipsToBounds to NO, I need to react to the scroll outside of the scroll view bounds. So I created ScrollForwarderView class which is subclass of UIView.

ScrollForwarderView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ScrollForwarderView : UIView
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIScrollView *scrollView;
@end
```

ScrollForwarderView.m

```
...
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if ([self pointInside:point withEvent:event]) {
        return _scrollView;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Then place UIView with custom class ScrollForwarderView above the scroll view, link scrollView property to my scroll view and it nicely forwarded the user events to scrollview.