# UIScrollView Paging Inset not working

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

How do you create a `UIScrollView` with pages that inset a little showing the next page? Like in this example:

[image]

My Current code as follows:

```
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
var colors = [UIColor.redColor(), UIColor.blueColor(), UIColor.greenColor(), UIColor.purpleColor(), UIColor.orangeColor()]

for var i = 0; i < colors.count; i++ {

    var rect:CGRect = CGRect()
    rect.origin.x = (scrollView.frame.size.width) * CGFloat(i)
    rect.size = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width, self.scrollView.frame.size.height)

    var subview:UIView = UIView(frame: rect)
    subview.backgroundColor = colors[i]
    scrollView.addSubview(subview)
}

self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(colors.count), self.scrollView.frame.size.height - 64)
```

Gives me this result (Sorry if it's not animating, feel free to refresh the page):

[image]

I have tried messing with code on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19067459/uiscrollview-paging-enabled-with-content-inset-is-working-strange) with no luck getting it to page correctly. (i.e. jumps too far or not far enough)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't attach code right now, but I've experimented with this in the past, and one approach you can take is to have the scroll view's frame the size of a single page (and not the entire screen), and set the clipSubviews property for the scroll view set to false. That way, you'll get the paging width you want and still see the next pages.

However, the problem that it presents is that you won't be able to scroll from the sides (outside the scroll view's frame, which doesn't cover the entire screen width now). In order to solve this, you can have another scrollview behind this scroll view, that covers the entire screen width. That scroll view will pass its touches to the 'real' scroll view and that way you'll get what you're trying to achieve and still cover the entire screen width for scrolling.

Comment: Do you by change remember how to pass the touches to the bottom scroll view?